# Css - Input sizes different resolutions and screen Sizes

Tags: css

I'd like to know the code in CSS so my two different input types be equal in every monitor.
So I have 1 big input type, and below 7 inputs that should cover the same width. Its all great in my 17.3inch monitor with fullhd. But in anothers, the seven inputs surpass the first one.
Here's the code:

```
input[type="text"] {
  font: 95% oxygen, sans-serif;
  border:2px solid rgb();
    width: 7%;
    height: 2%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 0%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;

}

input[type="text1"] {
  font: 95% oxygen, sans-serif;
  border:2px solid rgba();
    width: 50%;
    height: 2%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
```

Please help me, I saw every forum but I cant get it.[When its wrong, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1sc.png)

Comment: I dont know how to code, but this is obviously wrong

Comment: what is input type="text1"? Could you please share the HTML code as well?

Comment: @SachinSingh its the bigger one above the 7 smalls.  <input type="text1" name="Valorm2" placeholder="Property Location" list="Location" /> <p></p>
     <input type="text" name="M2" placeholder="Area" list="Area" /> it's simple like this the html code

Comment: What I meant was input type="text1" is not valid. Although browser will always default to the correct input type "text" if an unsupported type is specified. Please correct your HTML.

Comment: @SachinSingh why its not valid? I can attribute things only to it in css! thanks again. I changed to another name and its the same. I noticed that when I zoom in, it gets bigger that the search above. and when I zoom out, it gets smallers. Theres something in the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as per your scenario this solution should work:

```js
// JavaScript to toggle text placeholder for small inputs
$('.smallText').on('input', function () {
 if ($(this).val().length) {
   $(this).parent().addClass('empty');
 } else {
   $(this).parent().removeClass('empty');
 }
});
```

```css
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.largeText, .smallText {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.largeText {
  width: 100%;
}

.textWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.textWrapper+.textWrapper {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.textWrapper::before {
  content: 'small text...';
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  color: #777;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.textWrapper.empty::before {
  color: transparent;
}

.smallText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="large text..." class="largeText" />
  <div class="inner-container clearfix">
    <div class="textWrapper"><input type="text" class="smallText" /></div>
    <div class="textWrapper"><input type="text" class="smallText" /></div>
    <div class="textWrapper"><input type="text" class="smallText" /></div>
    <div class="textWrapper"><input type="text" class="smallText" /></div>
    <div class="textWrapper"><input type="text" class="smallText" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to apply javascript! I want to solve this only with css. thanks again @sachin

Comment: thanks man. I solved it. for related inputs I gotta use PX instead of %. It works now. I changed the whole website to % but some things better stay with px! thanks man